# powerpc-gcc inline assembly function

Tags: gcc, powerpc

i want to use mtspr instruction for a special purpose register whose number in passed to me in a function.

```
__MTSPR(unsigned int spr, long long val)
```

i have to put val in spr.

here is what i tried in vain.

```
    __asm__(
    "mtspr     %[a], %[b] "
    : : [a]"I"(spr), [b]"r"(val)
);
```

i get this error :

ppc_gnu.c: In function '__MTSPR':
ppc_gnu.c:69:2: warning: asm operand 0 probably doesn't match constraints [enabled by default]
ppc_gnu.c:69:2: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'

so how to solve this problem and please no MACROs. i can not modify this function's usage or declaration.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236791/powerpc-moving-to-variable-spr. (That u-boot related answer). And you can use that macro within your function.

Comment: thanks. seems like im stuck with the macro usage